# Natbib and Chicago

Tags: natbib, chicago-style

What's the quickest way to adopt the Chicago style for the bibliography (assuming `natbib` is used)?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx. It's customary here to not sign one's name, since it appears in a box to the bottom right of your post anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\bibliographystyle{chicago}` just before your `\bibliography` command.